# Group by label does not work

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am trying to display three graphs in one panel. The graphs are counting new signups in dependency to the oauth provider. Why "facebook" and "email" is not showing up in the final graph? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue still remains. Can anybody give an advice?

Answer (score 2):

i know this is more of a comment but as i am missing 4 reputation for being allowed to comment on questions and nobody commented on this for a week it still might be worth reading.

You could try splitting the one query into three like this:
 - `3600 * sum(rate(new_users_total{verification_method='google'}[1h]))`
 - `3600 * sum(rate(new_users_total{verification_method='facebook'}[1h]))`
 - `3600 * sum(rate(new_users_total{verification_method='email'}[1h]))`

Or you could use a templating like

i know this obviously does not scale but it might help with your issue.

Or you could try to reduce the interval like:
 - `300 * sum(rate(new_users_total[5m])) by (verification_method)` 
and remove the `Min step` value and let Grafana handle that for you.

And one question : did you try to display the original query (`3600 * sum(rate(new_users_total[1h])) by (verification_method)`) as a table? If so, does it show the missing values?